# What routine maintenance do you run on your Azure servers?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, maintenance-plan

I'm part of a team that maintains 20+ Azure servers.  Most of the servers are running 24-7 so we do not have weekly scheduled maintenance or anything.

Most virtual machines are Windows Server 2012, we have a few fairly active database servers running SQL 2014 on premium storage, others are web/IIS and file/application servers, and a terminal server.

What kind of maintenance should be done on our virtual machines to ensure that performance does not suffer? (De-fragmentation and stuff like that?) I'm curious as to what you guys do and how often you do it.

Thanks!
Joel

Comment: Not really a development question, should be posted under Server Fault